# Pass current item to ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` where I display all order positions. I need to display a price. I created a `ValueConverter` which takes a `OrderPosition` object and returns my price as double.
Formula:  Amount * Product.Price    (`Amount` and `Product` are properties in `OrderPosition`)

My XAML just won't display anything:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderPositions}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}x {1}">
                                <Binding Path="Amount" />
                                <Binding Path="Product.Label" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding /, Converter={StaticResource PositionPriceConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:c}}" Grid.Column="1"
                                   TextAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is my converter:

```
public class PositionPriceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var position = (OrderPosition)value;
        return position.Amount * position.Product.Price;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your converter?

Comment: I've added it. I assume that casting works, because my app doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: I guess that @dkozl is the best answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you set [`Path=/`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which binds it to `CollectionView.CurrentItem`

> When the source is a collection view, the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.

You can achieve what you're after by setting `Path=.` or not setting `Path` altogether.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter=...}
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter=...}
```

but be aware that it will not trigger update when either `Amount` or `Product.Price` will change so maybe `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter` would be better option.

Comment: Thanks that works. I've tried {Binding Path, Converter...} but received an error. Without comma it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
             <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Margin="3"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderPositions}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}x {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Amount" />
                                        <Binding Path="Product.Label" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionPriceConverter}" StringFormat="{}{0}x {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Amount" />
                                        <Binding Path="Product.Label" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Change the converter like this,

```
public class PositionPriceConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var amt = (double)values[0];
        var price = (double) values[1];
        return amt * price;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Am not sure if that path you provided to the binding is legal (`{Binding /, Converter....`).

try to change it in:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PositionPriceConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:c}}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" />
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource PositionPriceConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:c}}" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" />
```